# Simple request from mobile client to Meteor server

Tags: post, mobile, get, meteor, request

Using a browser client to interact with the DB in Meteor is almost trivial. However, I am having trouble retrieving data from a (non-js) mobile client. In a usual Django or PHP server, you simple do a GET or POST request from any client and respond whatever you want from the server, but Meteor works very different; I haven´t seen any example of how to respond from the server to a client.

If it's of interest, the mobile client uses C#.

**Edit:**
Extra question. Can you achieve this with IronRouter or somehow using DDP? Just read something about DDP so I am just posing an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use middleware for this purpose:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.stack.splice(0, 0, {
  route: '/api/endpoint',
  handle: function(req, res, next) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    res.end('{"success": true}');
  },
});
```

In the handle function, `req` and `res` are the usual Node.js requests and response objects and you can handle them in the same way as in a typical Node.js application. `next` is a function that you may call in case you decide that for some reason you don't want to respond to this request, and let Meteor propagate the request further through the stack.

Comment: Hmm. Can't find the docs for WebApp but will try it. Also, is IronRouter able to do this? Can you achieve this somehow with DDP protocol?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Work great :)